# internationalization issue in jquery.i18n.properties-1.0.9.js

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using the [jquery.i18n.properties-1.0.9.js](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/downloads/detail?name=jquery.i18n.properties-1.0.9.js&can=2&q=) for internationalization. In the fr culture file i have a entity

```
TaskString = tâche
```

in my html i have a code like this.
         j

```
      $.i18n.properties( {
            name: 'Strings',
            path: 'bundle/',
            mode: 'both',
            language: 'fr',
        } );
    $( document ).ready( function ()
       {
            $( '#Div1' ).html( TaskString );

     } );
```

what i need is  want to display the "task" in french like 'tâche'

but it displaying like this [image]

How to display a text in french like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change from tâche to `t&#226;che` in your FR properties file.

Comment: Actually i fix the issue by copying the char from character map(%windir%\system32\charmap.exe)

Comment: I usually convert special chars to html codes using this map http://www.tedmontgomery.com/tutorial/htmlchrc.html .